# How do I add a Checkbox on each row of my asp:Gridview if it's being populated from an ajax response

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

As the title says, I'm trying to add a check box to each row of my asp:gridview. The data from this gridview is being inserted from a function which is called after my ajax gets a response.

```
if (jsonResponse.ProductData.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < jsonResponse.ProductData.length; i++) {
                    $('#ctl00_Content_gvPrices').append("<tr>" +
                        "<td>" + " " + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + jsonResponse.ProductData[i].DATA1+ "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + jsonResponse.ProductData[i].DATA2+ "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + jsonResponse.ProductData[i].DATA3+ "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + jsonResponse.ProductData[i].DATA4+ "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + jsonResponse.ProductData[i].DATA5+ "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + jsonResponse.ProductData[i].DATA6+ "</td>" +
                        "</tr>");
            }
        }
```

This is the function I'm using to populate the gridview.
Below this is the grid view i'm populating.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvPrices" runat="server" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" Width="100%" >
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" CssClass="headerCheckBox" />
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" CssClass="rowCheckBox" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

I've tried to use the asp:TemplateField, it works for the header but not the items. I suspect it's because of the blank cell I have as the first td in the append, without this though my data goes into the incorrect columns.

Any idea what I'm missing ?

Answer (score 0):

May be silly but is the .net code within a

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
  your code here
}
```

I have seen similar issues before. sorry if no help.